# how can I install another version of perl on top of the default version on Centos

Tags: perl, centos

I'm working on Centos 6.3 and I need to install the latest version of perl. Because this is one of the dependencies of installing a package with rpm. So I installed it and I have it under a directory but the problem is that whenever I try perl -V it gives me the old version, so again when I try to install my other package with rpm command it gives me the same error of dependency!

Comment: Try adding the bin directory of your newly installed perl to the PATH environment variable in front of the path of the old perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/), it allows you to manage multiple perl installations in your $HOME directory, completely isolated each of them.

Example:

```
%> sudo cpan App::perlbrew
%> perlbrew init

%> perlbrew install perl-5.16.3
%> perlbrew switch perl-5.16.3
```

And now you have perl 5.16.3 in your PATH:

```
%> perl -v
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for ...
```